# How do I write a formatted string to a file?

Tags: rust

I want to write output of my function to a file. I expected that [`write_fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_fmt) is what I require:

```
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{BufWriter, Write},
};

fn main() {
    let write_file = File::create("/tmp/output").unwrap();
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(&write_file);

    // From my function
    let num = 1;
    let factorial = 1;

    writer.write_fmt("Factorial of {} = {}", num, factorial);
}
```

Error

```
error[E0061]: this function takes 1 parameter but 3 parameters were supplied
  --> src/main.rs:11:12
   |
11 |     writer.write_fmt("Factorial of {} = {}", num, factorial);
   |            ^^^^^^^^^ expected 1 parameter
```

This seems wrong and there isn't much available in the documentation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_fmt) indicates the issue: the `write_fmt` method takes one argument, of type [`std::fmt::Arguments`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html), which can be constructed via the [`format_args!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format_args.html) macro. It also suggests the best way to use it:

> The [`write!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.write.html) macro should be favored to invoke this method instead.

One calls [`write!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.write.html) (or [`writeln!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.writeln.html)) just like [`println!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.println.html), but by passing the location to write to as the first argument:

```
write!(&mut writer, "Factorial of {} = {}", num, factorial);
```

(Note that the docs have a search bar at the top of each page, so one can find documentation on, for example, macros by searching for `<name>!` there.)

Answer (score 8):

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let mut w = File::create("/tmp/test.txt").unwrap();
    writeln!(&mut w, "test").unwrap();
    writeln!(&mut w, "formatted {}", "arguments").unwrap();
}
```